# Create a new column with mutate according to conditional values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe **df** with columns ID, X and Y

```
ID = c(1,1,2,2)
X = c(1,0.4,0.8,0.1) 
Y = c(0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7)
df <- data.frame(ID,X,Y)

ID   X   Y
 1 1.0 0.5
 1 0.4 0.5
 2 0.8 0.7
 2 0.1 0.7
```

I would like to obtain two new columns:

- **Xg** equal to X when X is greater than Y and NA otherwise
- **Xl** equal to X when X is less than Y and NA otherwise. That is,

  ```
  ID   X   Y  Xg  Xl
   1 1.0 0.5 1.0  NA
   1 0.4 0.5  NA 0.4
   2 0.8 0.7 0.8  NA
   2 0.1 0.7  NA 0.1
  ```

Comment: Read about `ifelse`?

Comment: You say you have a dataframe but you're binding your data as a data.table. Do you mean `df <- data.frame(ID,X,Y)`? Or are you looking for a data.table solution?

Comment: @dshkol Since it printed without the usual `1:` seen in data.tables, I edited it to data.frame.

Comment: Look into `case_when` in the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried the following, but i still get an error because my original dataframe has NA  in X and Y : df1= mutate(df, Xg = ifelse(X > Y, X, NA)).

Comment: This is a ugly hack but reproduces your expected result: `Xg <- NA^(X <= Y) * X` `Xl <- NA^(X >= Y) * X`

Comment: Woww, that's smart!  I did not know `NA^0 = 1` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should work, even if there are NA's in `X` or `Y`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Xg = ifelse(X > Y, X, NA),
         Xl = ifelse(X < Y, Y, NA))
```

If you want to use `if_else` from `dplyr`, you have to convert NA to numeric. `if_else` is stricter than `ifelse` in that it checks whether the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values are the same type:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Xg = if_else(X > Y, X, as.numeric(NA)),
         Xl = if_else(X < Y, Y, as.numeric(NA)))
```

**Result:**

```
  ID   X   Y  Xg  Xl
1  1 1.0 0.5 1.0  NA
2  1 0.4 0.5  NA 0.5
3  2 0.8 0.7 0.8  NA
4  2 0.1 0.7  NA 0.7
5  3  NA 1.0  NA  NA
6  3 3.0  NA  NA  NA
```

**Data:**

```
ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
X = c(1,0.4,0.8,0.1,NA,3) 
Y = c(0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7,1,NA)
df <- data.frame(ID,X,Y)
```

Comment: You can use `NA_real_` instead of `as.numeric(NA)`

Comment: @OttToomet True, that's what `as.numeric()` is converting `NA` to anyway. (`identical(as.numeric(NA), NA_real_)`

Answer (score 2):

What about some plain old R indexing and subsetting?

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2, 3, 3)
X <- c(1,0.4,0.8,0.1, NA, 2) 
Y <-  c(0.5,0.5,0.7,0.7, 2, NA)
Xg <- Xl <- rep(NA_real_, length(ID))
Xg[which(X > Y)] <- X[which(X > Y)]
Xl[which(X < Y)] <- X[which(X < Y)]
data.frame(ID, X, Y, Xg, Xl)
```

Note: I assume that if X or Y is missing, Xg and Xl should be NA.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness and as the question originally used `data.table()` before it was edited (and because I like the concise code) here is "one-liner" using `data.table`'s *update in place*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[X > Y, Xg := X][X < Y, Xl := X][]
```

> ```
>    ID   X   Y  Xg  Xl
> 1:  1 1.0 0.5 1.0  NA
> 2:  1 0.4 0.5  NA 0.4
> 3:  2 0.8 0.7 0.8  NA
> 4:  2 0.1 0.7  NA 0.1
> 5:  3  NA 1.0  NA  NA
> 6:  3 3.0  NA  NA  NA
> ```

(Using the data of [useR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416511/3817004))

`NA`'s are handled automatically as only matching rows are updated.